# if condition on $stateProvider in config

Tags: angularjs, config

In my project I have displayed my navigation menus using :

```
function config($stateProvider, msNavigationServiceProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('app.contacts', {
        url    : '/contacts',
        views  : {
            'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/contacts/contacts.html',
                controller : 'ContactsController as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {

        }
    });

    //For Navigation
    msNavigationServiceProvider.saveItem('apps.contacts', {
        title : 'Contacts',
        icon  : 'icon-account-box',
        state : 'app.contacts',
        weight: 10
    });
}
```

Now I want to show navigation on a condition that when super admin has assigned the sub user its permission. So what I should do in that condition?

Until now I tried adding this $stateProvider.state and msNavigationServiceProvider.saveItem in if condition, where in if contained a response from a service (a service which defines which items should appear in navigation), but this isn't working, calling of service is not allowed in config.

So what should I do for this?

Comment: What do you mean by show navigation?  Are we talking about only allow navigation to certain pages based upon a condition?

Comment: I want to show navigation to when logged in with particular user only

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a conditional to hide navigation in the header?